# Iterate Linked List and map with the properties file value

Tags: java, servlets, properties, iterator, linked-list

I have `country.properties` file which have values as follows:

```
1=USA
91=India
20=Egypt
358=Finland
33=France
679=Fiji
```

and, have a response class file, which is setting a response from database to display it on `JSP` file. The value that I am getting from database is in the form of `code` or `integer`. I needed to have that value from the database and before setting the response I need to use `getProperty(code)` and save the String representation of that code into a new list and then pass that list to `setResponse`. For e.g: This is the value I am getting from database:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 |
 1     helo   done
```

I needed to show on my JSP page as:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 |
 USA   helo   done
```

I was following this tutorial,http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/.
but not able to exactly understand how to achieve the same.

This is my `DAOImpl` where I needed to `iterate` and save the `mapped key-value` in a new list and then pass to `JSP` page

```
public class CountDAOImpl implements IDataDAO {
    private Connection conn = null;
    private Statement statement = null;
    private ResultSet rs = null;
    private List<String> country_code = new LinkedList<String>();
//created a new list to put mapped string value instead of code   
   private List<String> countryMapValue = new LinkedList<String>();

      public CountResponse getValue(String query) throws Exception {
        CountResponse response = new CountResponse();
        try {
            conn = DBConnection.getInstance().getCpds().getConnection();
            statement = conn.createStatement();
            rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
            // Extract data from result set
            while (rs.next()) {
                //Retrieve by column name
                String cc = rs.getString("country_code");
                country_code.add(cc);
                }
                //Setting the Response
                response.setCountry(country_code);
                     } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return response;
    }
```

Any help on this would be great, as I am new to programming field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all load the property file by following the tutorial from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)

```
... // loading properties file code here

//load a properties file from class path
prop.load(input);
```

Then, add the below line to extract the value from the property file given a key in your while loop itself -

Sample example below -

```
//Retrieve by column name
String cc = rs.getString("country_code");
country_code.add(prop.getProperty(cc));
```

Comment: can you share some examples or ways, of how to iterate a linked list and put into a new linked list?